# Compare 2 columns from different tables in database

Tags: mysql, database

Im trying to compare 2 columns (difficulty, difficulty_student) from 2 different tables (EXERCISES, ANSWERS) and create a new column in table ANSWERS comparing both tables with a Boolean (YES or NO). If the user has changed the difficulty of the exercise, the cell will be 'YES', if it has not been changed, the cell will be 'NO'.

These are my 2 tables. I want to compare ‘difficulty’ from table EXERCISES and ‘difficulty_student’ from table ANSWERS, and store it in ‘difficulty_chage’ in table ANSWERS.

```
CREATE TABLE exercises (
    exercise_id INT,
    difficulty INT
    PRIMARY KEY(exercise_id)
);

CREATE TABLE answers(
    exercise_id_fk INT,
    student_id INT,
    difficulty_change BOOLEAN,
    difficulty_student INT,
    choice_answer INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(exercise_id_fk) REFERENCES exercises(exercise_id)
);
```

This is what I have tried but doesn’t work, can you help me?

```
SELECT exercises.difficulty, answers.difficulty_student, 
       IF(difficulty = difficulty_student, NO) as difficulty_change
FROM answers
ELSE 'YES' as difficulty_change FROM answers
```

This is what I would like it to be:

[image]

Comment: It would probably be more useful to provide your SQL, not your PHP. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry I eddited my question. Is it more useful?

Comment: Relative to what?

Comment: update  yoru question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: i don't see  any data sample ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to persist the changes on the DB, you could use an update statement:

```
update answers 
inner join exercises on answers.exercise_id_fk = exercises.exercise_id 
set answers.difficulty_change = 'YES' 
where answers.difficulty_student != exercises.difficulty;
```

Note: the *difficulty_change* column should be a VARCHAR(3) for the *answers* table to work with values 'YES' or 'NO'. I'm assuming your *answers* table has by default the 'NO' value on the *difficulty_change* column.

Here's the schema and data I used to test the query:

```
CREATE TABLE exercises (
    exercise_id INT,
    difficulty INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(exercise_id)
);

CREATE TABLE answers(
    exercise_id_fk INT,
    student_id INT,
    difficulty_change VARCHAR(3),
    difficulty_student INT,
    choice_answer INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(exercise_id_fk) REFERENCES exercises(exercise_id)
);

insert into exercises values (1,1);
insert into exercises values (2,2);
insert into exercises values (3,3);
insert into exercises values (4,4);
insert into exercises values (5,5);

insert into answers values (1,1,'NO',1,1);
insert into answers values (2,1,'NO',2,1);
insert into answers values (3,1,'NO',3,1);
insert into answers values (4,1,'NO',5,1);
insert into answers values (5,1,'NO',4,1);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works with `SELECT e.difficulty, a.difficulty_student, 
case when e.difficulty = a.difficulty_student then 'NO' else 'YES' 
         END  as difficulty_change
FROM exercises e 
INNER JOIN answers a  on e.exercise_id=a.exercise_id_fk;` This code compares both columns but I don't know in which table is saving the Boolean values, I would like to save them in the ANSWERS table in the difficulty_change column... Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Yes, if you use the query I provided it will save the boolean values in the difficult_change column on the ANSWERS table. The "set answers.difficulty_change = 'YES'" code does the trick.
The query you mentioned is a select, so it provides the data you need but it doesn't update the table. To update the table, you need an UPDATE statement as the one I provided :)

Comment: I tried your code but its not working, I have this error: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from answers inner join exercises on answers.exercise_id_fk = exercises.exercise' at line 3 0.000 sec`

Comment: It may be related to some of the inconsistencies between your DB structure and the structure you posted on the question. I've updated the post with my testing schema, compare it with yours and you'll see what's wrong on it. Remember to update the difficulty_change column data type.

Comment: The problem is that the column `'difficulty_change'` cannot compare values until the user press the `'submit'` button, which is when they enter or not the value of the column `'difficulty_student' `and thus be able to compare it with 'difficulty' `from the table EXERCISES .

Comment: I think you have to approaches to solve your problem.  
The first approach is the one we've been talking about, using SQL. But you should perform this one on two steps:  
1. insert the records on the answers table when the user clicks the 'submit' button, assigning 'NO' to the difficulty_change field.  
2. Run the UPDATE query to assign the right values to the difficulty_change column.  
The other approach is to compare in the backend the data submitted by the user with the EXERCISES.difficulty field on the DB and INSERT the corresponding value on ANSWERS.difficulty_change column.

Comment: Im not sure if I understand you...After this how should I proceed? `UPDATE answers a 
INNER JOIN exercises e  on e.exercise_id=a.exercise_id_fk 
set a.difficulty_change = case 
     when e.difficulty = a.difficulty_student then 'NO' else 'YES' END
where e.exercise_id=a.exercise_id_fk;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178074/discussion-between-streiten-and-ana).

Answer (score 2):

In you pricture there is not a table user but exercise and answer  so
You could join the table  (assuming by relation based on exercise_id)

```
SELECT e.difficulty, a.difficulty_student, 
case when e.difficulty = a.difficulty_student then 'NO' else 'YES' 
         END  as difficulty_change
FROM exercises e 
INNER JOIN answer a  on e.exercise_id=a.exercise_id_fk
```

for change the column  difficulty_change in table answer you should use an updated ...  but you have int in your difficulty_change column so or you use a numeric result for query eg:

```
UPDATE answer a 
INNER JOIN exercises e  on e.exercise_id=a.exercise_id_fk
set a.difficulty_change =   case when e.difficulty = a.difficulty_student then 0 else 1 END
where e.exercise_id=a.exercise_id_fk
```

or you must change the data typr for difficulty_change  as  varchar(3)  and use

```
UPDATE answer a 
INNER JOIN exercises e  on e.exercise_id=a.exercise_id_fk 
set a.difficulty_change = case 
     when e.difficulty = a.difficulty_student then 'NO' else 'YES' END
where e.exercise_id=a.exercise_id_fk
```